# Symbol "k" not found on my nested for loops?

Tags: c++

So I'm making this deck of cards using card objects, basically for every card "i" in my array I set the card number to "i", here comes the nested loop, which loops 4 times to set the "Heart", "Spade", "Club", "Diamond" suit and I get this error. I am fairly new to c++, so I don't know anything else new from what you see in the code. I'd like some ideas, thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

class card
{
public:
    int number;
    string suit;
    card()
    {
        number = 0;
        suit = "Suitless";
    }
    card(int x, string y)
    {
        number = x;
        suit = y;
    }
};

class deck
{
private:
    //array to hold some cards.  Array is allocated by constructor
    card * cardArray;

    //size of cardArray, set by constructor
    int maxSize;     

    //Number of cards in deck.  Should not exceed maxSize.
    int numCards;

public:
    //default constructor:  create the standard 52 card deck
    deck()
    {
        maxSize = 52;
        cardArray = new card[maxSize];
        numCards = 0;
    }
    //parameterized constructor:  create a special deck that has
    //card numbers from 1 to numberRange and numSuits different suits.
    //In addition, the names of the different suits will be provided
    //by the array of strings 'suitList'.  This constructor should
    //create a card for each possible pairing of a number and a suit.
    //Therefore, there should be numberRange*numSuits total cards.
    //If numberRange=13, numSuits=4, and
    //suitList = {"heart","club","spade","diamond"}, then this constructor
    //should create the same deck that would be created by
    //the default constructor.
    deck(int numberRange, int numSuits, string * suitList)
    {               
        //numberRange = 13;
        //numSuits = 4;

        /*string * suitList = new string[maxSize] = {"heart", "club", "spade", "diamond"};*/


        for(int i=1; i<=numberRange; i++){

            for(int k=1;k<=numSuits;k++){
                cardArray[k].number = i;    
            }
            for(int j=1; j<=numSuits; j++){
                cardArray[j].suit = suitList[j];
            }
        }
        //fix for Ace
        /*for(int i=0;i<maxSize;i++){
            if(cardArray[i].number == 1){
                cardArray[i].number = NULL;
                cardArray[i].suit = "Ace";
            }
        }*/

    }


    //place input card onto top of deck
    void addCardTop(card c)
    {
        //push
        cardArray[maxSize] = c;
        numCards++;
    }

    //remove and return the card at the top of the deck
    card dealCardFromTop()
    {
        //pop
        card dealt = cardArray[numCards - 1];
        numCards--;
        return dealt;
    }

    //remove and return a random card from the deck
    card dealRandomCard()
    {
        card randCard;
        srand(time(NULL));
        int a = rand() % 53 + 1;

        randCard = cardArray[a];
        return randCard;
    }

    //rearrange all the cards in the deck into random order
    void shuffle()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<53; i++){
            int r = i + (rand() % (52 - i));
            card temp = cardArray[i];
            cardArray[i] = cardArray[r];
            cardArray[r] = temp;
        }
    }

    //Cut the deck at position'p':  swap the lower portion
    //of the card array (from 0 to p-1) with the
    //top portion of the deck (position p to numCards-1).
    void cut(int p)
    {
        int end = (p+1);
        for(int i=1; i<=numCards; i++){
            card temp = cardArray[i];
            cardArray[i] = cardArray[end];
            cardArray[end] = temp;
            end++;
        }
    }

    //arrange the cards into increasing order by card number.
    void sort()
    {
        card min;
        min = cardArray[0];
        for(int i=1; i<maxSize; i++){
            if(min.number < cardArray[i].number)
                min = cardArray[i];
        }

    }
    void print()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<maxSize; i++){
            cout << cardArray[i].number << cardArray[i].suit << endl;   
        }
    }
};

int main(){


    string suitList[] = {"Heart", "Spade", "Club", "Diamond"};
    deck a(13, 4, suitList);
    card b;
    a.addCardTop(b);
    a.print();


    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please include the full error and tell use where it occurs.

Comment: Just so you know, C++ (and many other languages) use `0` based indexing, so your loops are going to go out of bounds `int k=1;k<=numSuits;k++`

Comment: Unfortunately the program does not compile, due to an "Access violation". I have an idea on where it is, but I am not sure how to fix it.                                                          Edit: I believe the error is here... `cardArray[k].number = i;`

Comment: @SamPerales Read my comment literally one above yours. Your loops should look like `int k=0;k<numSuits;k++`

Comment: @Cyber, I just tried it. I'm still getting the same error :(

Comment: As a side note. In constructor you allocate space on the heap `cardArray = new card[maxSize];` yet there is no destructor defined to release this space. Thus you have memory leak. Deallocate this space, or use smart pointers.

Comment: @Marcin, where do you suggest I delete the allocated space, in main, or in the class def?

Comment: In a destructor `~deck() {delete [] cardArray; }`

Comment: @SamPerales _"Access violation"_ Isn't a compiler error, but appears at runtime. So you debug your program, stepping through line by line.

Answer (score 0):

You are using uninitialized variable `cardArray` in for loop in     `deck::deck(int numberRange, int numSuits, string * suitList)`. 
Add memory allocation before the for loop or even better into initializer list.

Please don't forget that arrays are indexed from 0 and not from 1. `for(int k=1;k<=numSuits;k++)` should be better written as `for(int k=0;k<numSuits;k++)`